# Spring AOP - aspect loop execution

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

in first and foremost i need to say that I'm new in Spring AOP (well, I'm new in AOP at all).
In my application I have service class which is advised by aspect, unitil this point is everyting fine. Aspect is triggered, everyting works. But I need to call that service method from my aspect, and there is problem. My Aspect is (logicaly) triggered for each call and everyting end on StackOwerflow error.

It is possible to prevent that aspect looping ?

I have idea to create IAspectSandbox interface (or class) and method invocations from class which will implement this interface do not trigger aspects. But I really don't know how to achieve this goal :)

My class schema:

```
@Service
public class MyService 
{
  public BarObject update( FooObject item )
  {
      BarObject barObject = new BarObject();
      // save FooObject to database and detect changes against old row
      // information about fields, that was changed is in BarObject
      return barObject;
  }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Aspect
public class MyServicePointcut 
{
    @Pointcut("execution(*  cz.package.service.MyService.update(..))")  
    public void myServiceItemChanged() {}   
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Component
@Aspect
public class PraceZadaniChangeAspect 
{

  @AutoWire
  private MyService myService;


  @AfterReturning("cz.package.pointcuts.MyServicePointcut.myServiceItemChanged()", returning = "returnVal")  
    public void execute( BarObject returnVal )
    {
        // do something with BarObject ... mostly check changes
            // .....
            // .....
            // at the end I need to save changes
        myService.update( returnVal.getFooObject() ); // after this call is this aspect triggered again. I know why, but I don't want to :)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer #1: Calling Advised Method Only (Around Advice)**

If you autowire your service back into your aspect, you're still invoking Spring's proxy mechanism, including the AOP aspect that you've applied to your service.

See "Around Advice" in the Spring AOP chapter:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice

Basically, do something like this:

```
@AfterReturning("...")
public void execute(ProceedingJoinPoint p, BarObject returnVal)
{
    // do something with BarObject
    // ...
    // call original method with original args
    p.proceed(p.getArgs());
}
```

I am not 100% sure on the code, but `proceed()` should call the target method directly without invoking the AOP proxy recursively.

**Answer #2: Calling Multiple Target Object Methods**

If you need to call multiple methods from that service object within your aspect, you'll need access to the unproxied object via `getTarget()`:

```
@AfterReturning("...")
public void execute(JoinPoint p, BarObject returnVal)
{
    // do something with BarObject
    // ...
    // call various service methods without triggering this AOP proxy again
    // by using getTarget() to get the unproxied object:
    MyService myService = (MyService) p.getTarget();
    myService.update(...);               // does not trigger AOP interceptor
    myService.otherMethod(...);          // neither does this
    myService.thirdMethod(...);          // nor this
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I was thinking about to write pointcut rule. Somehow exclude calls from specific class (or class which implement specific interface). But I'm not sure if is this possible.

Comment: You could execlude classes in a pointcut using '!'.. check the reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-combining)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I need to exclude class which invoking that service class method. I need to exclude all method invocations from my aspect to the service class. I'm not sure if is this possible in Spring AOP.

Comment: See Answer #2 that I added to the response, above - I think that answers your question.  On the other hand, if you've got a pointcut defined on one object and are trying to avoid the AOP proxy to another object: (a) you can do this by creating your own proxy object - the proxy object gets AOP advice and just delegates every method to the original MyService object, which doesn't get any AOP advice, and (b) you probably need to re-think how your code is structured.

Comment: @BobG You are my Hero, it is really working. Thank you, you helped me alot. The truth is, i'm not sure if I'm using aspects well. In my application, I need to listen on some events, like "record A was changed, do something or call something". At first I created my own implementation of event listeners, but I was not satisfied. After that I read about AOP in spring docs and I was happy about that. That was exactly what I needed. Really nice decoupled "listeners", the advised object don't know about aspects and I don't need to hardcode some hooks to trigger listeners.

Comment: @Peter: Glad it works.  I can't comment on your case specifically, but I try to err on the side of adding the code in-line using well-defined design patterns.  Having said that, there are instances where AOP can easily and quickly solve a specific problem.  It might be worth your while to spend a few minutes thinking about if an explicit listener or interceptor model would be clearer and/or more maintainable than using an aspect.

Comment: @BobG Before I switched my application to the Spring, I tried the listeners and I was not so satisfied, I had the same problem with recursion :).I solved this problem with listener switches,so,when I called my service I needed somethink like this: "mySrv.disableListeners();mySrv.update(..); mySrv.enableListeners();" and that was really ugly :). And in my service was something like this "if(listenersEnabled) dispatch( ItemChangedEvent )".After switch to Spring, I can not use this approach anymore, because services are "stateless singletons" and listener disabling could affect other requests.

Comment: @BobG (cont) On the other hand, using AOP for my purposes is overkill (maybe). But I really like that AOP decoupling, advised objects don't need to do anything to populate changes/events in application. No hooks or event dispatchers. But still, I feel that I a little bit exploiting that Spring AOP approach :)